# deSolve in R: error with number of derivatives returned

Tags: r, interpolation, differential-equations, desolve

I am currently trying to create a function that will solve a compartment model using the deSolve function. The parameters are variable over time so I have used approxfun() to interpolate the parameter estimates. I have 4 variables and currently 122 time steps in my dummy data set. When I try to run the function, I get this error:

`Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) :  The number of derivatives returned by func() (488) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (4)`

I will paste my code below! Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am expecting to get an output which is a dataframe of the value of each variable (E, L, L3f, L3p) at each time point.

Comment: I think I see an issue.  Your rate function `para.dyn` requires a third argument of parameters that I don't believe are getting passed to it.  The call to `lsoda` uses `param = NULL`.  A general piece of advice is to write the rate function so it's more independent and can be called like `rate_fn(0, y0, param)` as a test.  The way you've coded this is that the rate function is nested in another function and can't be called independently.  It's difficult to test and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter names in the equations are mistyped and refer to the global vectors, not the interpolated values. A corrected version should look like this:

```r
      # Differential equations
      dE <- -(mu1 + (2 * dev1)) * E + 100
      dL <- -(mu2 + (2 * dev1)) * L + (2 * dev1) * E
      dL3f <- -(mu3 + mig1) * L3f + (2 * dev1) * L
      dL3p <- -mu4 * (L3p * (1 - mig2)) - mu5 * (mig2 * L3p) + mig1 * L3f
```

[image: simulation results]

### A few additional hints

- Better use `time` in the model function (i.e. the actual time step) instead of `times` that is the vector of all time steps. It is not an error, but would improve readability.
- Consistently use `<-` for assignments, not sometimes `=` and sometimes `<-`. The equal `=`-sign should only be used for named parameter matching.
- To make debugging easier in the future, try to simplify your code before posting. So for example, avoid nested function definitions.
- To debug your code yourself, add `print` or `cat` statements within your code, or (even better) set breakpoints in RStudio with "Debug - Toggle Breakpoints".

Comment: Ahh great, thanks so much for your comment! I'd been looking at this so long that I didn't even notice the difference between the global vectors and interpolated values. Thank you for the other tips too, super helpful!